# Protractor for loop

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to check 75 elements of a menu. The menu has a search area and the elements. What I want to do is a for that takes each element from my list, enters the text of the element into the search area, verify if the element exists in the list, then clear the search area and enter the second element and so on. After the first element is entered, checked and the search area is cleared, the program stops and gives the error : Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. I know that this is a problem with the promises, but I already tried everything that I could find about for loop promises in protractor(each, map, bluebird etc.). Nothing is working...

```
enterElementsInSearchArea : function()
{
    var menuLinks = this.menuLinks;
    /*var searchArea = this.searchArea;*/

    function searchElement(text)
    {
        var menuLinks = element.all(by.css('.first-level > ul > li > a'));
        var searchArea = element(by.id('search'));
        searchArea.sendKeys(text);
        //console.log(search);
        expect(menuLinks.count()).toBe(1);
        searchArea.clear();
        expect(menuLinks.count()).toBe(menuLinks.length);
    };

    menuLinks.then(function(items)
    {
        for(var i in items) 
        {
            (function(i) 
            {
                // console.log('here1');
                // browser.pause();
                items[i].getText().then(function(text)
                {
                    console.log(i);
                    // browser.pause();
                     searchElement(text);
                    // console.log('here3');
                    // browser.pause();
                });  
            })(i);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your immediately invoked function expression should do the trick for the looping... as would `each`.

I suspect your issue is in your `searchElement()` method... you may just need a wait till the app is back in ready state. Try something like:

```
var menuLinks = element.all(by.css('.first-level > ul > li > a'));
var searchArea = element(by.id('search'));

function searchElement(text) {
    searchArea.sendKeys(text);

    expect(menuLinks.count()).toBe(1);

    // cleanup... 
    searchArea.clear();
    browser.wait(function() {
        // or something that indicates ready state...
        return menuLinks.count() > 1;
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is when I invoke searchArea.sendKeys(text) the second time in searchElement function. The first time is entering, but in the second try it gives me "Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". I rewrite it as you said, but I get the same error.